# Combine two dissimilar arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I'm looking to loop over an array of integer items and push each of the element into a distinct object array item. What's the best way to achieve this?

```
var intArr = [111, 112, 113];
var langData = [{
    "region": "Africa",
    "country": "Algeria",
    "territory": null,
    "territoryCode": "DZ",
    "localLanguage": {
      "territoryId": 3,
      "localLanguageName": "Arabic, French",
      "localLanguageCode": "ARA,FRE"
    }
  },
  {
    "region": "Africa",
    "country": "Angola",
    "territory": null,
    "territoryCode": "AO",
    "localLanguage": {
      "territoryId": 4,
      "localLanguageName": "Portuguese",
      "localLanguageCode": "POR"
    }
  },
  {
    "region": "Africa",
    "country": "Benin",
    "territory": null,
    "territoryCode": "BJ",
    "localLanguage": {
      "territoryId": 5,
      "localLanguageName": "French",
      "localLanguageCode": "FRE"
    }
  }
]
```

My desired output should have a length of intArr.length * langData.length.
Apart from using multiple for loops, is there any other way ?
My output should look something like below

```
var tLangData = [{
    "region": "Africa",
    "val": 111,
    "country": "Algeria",
    "territory": null,
    "territoryCode": "DZ",
    "localLanguage": {
      "territoryId": 3,
      "localLanguageName": "Arabic, French",
      "localLanguageCode": "ARA,FRE"
    }
  },
  {
    "region": "Africa",
    "val": 111,
    "country": "Angola",
    "territory": null,
    "territoryCode": "AO",
    "localLanguage": {
      "territoryId": 4,
      "localLanguageName": "Portuguese",
      "localLanguageCode": "POR"
    }
  },
  {
    "region": "Africa",
    "val": 111,
    "country": "Benin",
    "territory": null,
    "territoryCode": "BJ",
    "localLanguage": {
      "territoryId": 5,
      "localLanguageName": "French",
      "localLanguageCode": "FRE"
    }
  },
  {
    "region": "Africa",
    "val": 112,
    "country": "Algeria",
    "territory": null,
    "territoryCode": "DZ",
    "localLanguage": {
      "territoryId": 3,
      "localLanguageName": "Arabic, French",
      "localLanguageCode": "ARA,FRE"
    }
  },
  {
    "region": "Africa",
    "val": 112,
    "country": "Angola",
    "territory": null,
    "territoryCode": "AO",
    "localLanguage": {
      "territoryId": 4,
      "localLanguageName": "Portuguese",
      "localLanguageCode": "POR"
    }
  },
  {
    "region": "Africa",
    "val": 112,
    "country": "Benin",
    "territory": null,
    "territoryCode": "BJ",
    "localLanguage": {
      "territoryId": 5,
      "localLanguageName": "French",
      "localLanguageCode": "FRE"
    }
  },
  {
    "region": "Africa",
    "val": 113,
    "country": "Algeria",
    "territory": null,
    "territoryCode": "DZ",
    "localLanguage": {
      "territoryId": 3,
      "localLanguageName": "Arabic, French",
      "localLanguageCode": "ARA,FRE"
    }
  },
  {
    "region": "Africa",
    "val": 113,
    "country": "Angola",
    "territory": null,
    "territoryCode": "AO",
    "localLanguage": {
      "territoryId": 4,
      "localLanguageName": "Portuguese",
      "localLanguageCode": "POR"
    }
  },
  {
    "region": "Africa",
    "val": 113,
    "country": "Benin",
    "territory": null,
    "territoryCode": "BJ",
    "localLanguage": {
      "territoryId": 5,
      "localLanguageName": "French",
      "localLanguageCode": "FRE"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need it, here is the traditional method of nested `for` loops, which will give you the desired result.

```
const combine = (ints, data) => {
  let res = [];
  for (let i of ints) {
    for (let d of data) {
      d['val'] = i;
      res.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d)));
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(combine(intArr, langData));
```

If you're familiar [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), the approach below avoids explicit loops altogether. We first use `flatMap` to duplicate each of the `intArr` elements 3 times (i.e. `langData.length` times). Then, we apply `map` to include all the integer values across all the regional info. Note also, the use of the modulo operator to re-use the `langData` elements.

```
const combined = intArr.flatMap(i => Array(langData.length).fill(i)).map((e, i) => {
  langData[i % langData.length]['val'] = e;
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(langData[i % langData.length]));
});
console.log(combined);
```

Note: `flatMap` is ES10+, which is widely supported. If you need to support older browsers, you can try using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) combined with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const result = intArr.reduce(
  (obj, int) => [...obj, ...langData.map(lang => ({ ...lang, val: int }))],
  []
);
```